# GoldenLayout(ipygoldenlayout): How to programmatically change Tabs?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, golden-layout, ipyvuetify

I'm trying to find a way to programmatically change tabs in ipyGoldenLayout. Is there any way I could do it?
[image: Here are the tabs I want to be able to switch tabs.]

```
import ipyvuetify as v
from traitlets import Unicode
from ipygoldenlayout import GoldenLayout

gl = GoldenLayout()

class TestGL(v.VuetifyTemplate):
    template = Unicode("""
    <golden-layout style="height: 200px">
      <gl-row>
        <gl-component title="component1">
          <h1>Component 1</h1>
        </gl-component>
        <gl-stack>
          <gl-component title="component2">
            <h1>Component 2</h1>
          </gl-component>
          <gl-component title="component3">
            <h1>Component 3</h1>
          </gl-component>
        </gl-stack>
      </gl-row>
    </golden-layout>
    """).tag(sync=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out and here's the answer.

```
import ipyvuetify as v
from traitlets import Unicode
from ipygoldenlayout import GoldenLayout

gl = GoldenLayout()
class TestGL(v.VuetifyTemplate):
    tabs = Any("1").tag(sync=True)
    template = Unicode("""
    <golden-layout style="height: 200px">
      <gl-row>
        <gl-component title="component1">
          <h1>Component 1</h1>
        </gl-component>
        <gl-stack v-model="tabs">
          <gl-component title="component2" tab-id="1">
            <h1>Component 2</h1>
          </gl-component>
          <gl-component title="component3" tab-id="2">
            <h1>Component 3</h1>
          </gl-component>
        </gl-stack>
      </gl-row>
    </golden-layout>
    """).tag(sync=True)

obj = TestGL()
```

I can call `obj.tabs = "2"` to switch to the tab with component 3 programmatically.